# Excel macro to find a specified value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Date & Time in B1 column and amount in D1 column.

I need a macro to search specified amount is there in my sheet and if found copy amount as well as date to next sheet. Multiple occurrences happen.

It would be better if a search box is included.

Thanks

Here is a code which i found out from internet works fine but here it search for the word "mailbox" and also there is no search box available.
Sub SearchForString()

```
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Start search in row 4
LSearchRow = 4

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 2

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

    'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
    If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Mail Box" Then

        'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
        Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Move counter to next row
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

'Position on cell A3
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A3").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub
```

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any code examples we can see?

Comment: you need to be more specific and more clear!!! What have you tried so far?

Comment: [**This link**](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can adapt:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim K As Long, N As Long, i As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    K = 1
    s1.Select
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    v = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=1)
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, "D").Value = v Then
            Cells(i, "B").Copy s2.Cells(K, "B")
            Cells(i, "D").Copy s2.Cells(K, "D")
        K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using this code but search values are not copied to next sheet